# Mandrill with php to send .xls attachment, blank file

Tags: php, xls, mandrill

Is it just me or is there almost no documentation on how to do this? Mandrill's site isn't much help. Anyway...here's the problem...

```
try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('API_KEY');
    $attachment = file_get_contents("../template.xls");
    $attachment_encoded = base64_encode($attachment);
    $message = array(
        'html' => '<p>Some html text</p>',
        'text' => 'Some text',
        'subject' => 'Subject',
        'from_email' => 'email@domain.com',
        'from_name' => 'Name',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => 'myemail@domain.com',
                'name' => 'Name',
                'type' => 'to'
            )
        ),
        'attachments' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                'name' => 'New_Features_Submission.xls',
                'path' => $attachment_encoded
            )
        )
    );
    $async = false;
    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Mandrill_Error $e) {
    echo 'A Mandrill error occured: ' . get_class($e) . '-' . $e->getMessage();
    throw $e;
}
```

The email sends correctly, but I can't even open the .xls file. I tried using 'application/xls' for the type, that didn't work either. I'm not familiar with encoding, help please!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
'path' => $attachment_encoded
```

Needs to be this:

```
'content' => $attachment_encoded
```